# Converting an image to pre-defined 16 colors

Tags: php, colors, gd

Given an image file, what's the best way to convert it to the old school 16 colors? i.e. white, orange, magenta, light blue, yellow, lime, pink, gray, light gray, cyan, purple, blue, brown, green, red, and black.

I've made a little 1x16 pixel image containing all 16 of those colors that I can use as a source palette (right?) but I'm having trouble making use of it. It seems like `imagepalettecopy()` is what I want (take the 16 pixel data image's color palette and copy it onto a fresh image) but the code I came up with isn't working:

```php
<?php

$palette = imagecreatefrompng( __DIR__ . '/palette.png' );

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( __DIR__ . '/testimage.jpg' );

$source_w = imagesx( $source );
$source_h = imagesy( $source );

$image = imagecreate( $source_w, $source_h );

imagepalettecopy( $palette, $image );

imagecopy( $image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $source_w, $source_h );

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng( $image );
```

It seems to just convert it to 16 colors of it's choosing or something (I'm not quite sure).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

EDIT: My `imagepalettecopy()` call is backwards but fixing it doesn't help either. See below comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does changing
imagepalettecopy($palette, $image);
into
imagepalettecopy($image, $palette);
work?

**EDIT:**

I tried the following palette as a gif:

[image]

I think these colors are different from yours.
(I hand picked the greens from the picture...)

This is the code I tried (not really a difference here):

```
<?php

$palette = imagecreatefromgif('palette-gif-03.gif');

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg('test-image-01.jpg');

$source_w = imagesx($source);
$source_h = imagesy($source);

$image = imagecreate($source_w, $source_h);

imagepalettecopy($image, $palette);

imagecopy($image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $source_w, $source_h);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($imgage);
imagedestroy($palette);
imagedestroy($source);
?>
```

And this was my result:

[image]

Please let me know if I should delete the picture?!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No, that maintains the original many-color palette. My above code does change the image and significantly reduce it's number of colors but it seems to reduce it to 16 colors of it's choosing (in my case many shades of blue and gray).

Comment: Strange, because the manual says imagepalettecopy (resource $destination , resource $source). Can you add an exemplary source image and the resulting image to your question?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. Bug in my code. However both orders (my accidental wrong and the correct order) result in similar but wrong images. Test image: http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/20130511-110556.jpg Correct order (image, palette): http://pic.armedcats.net/b/bl/blue/2013/05/15/imagepalette.png Original backwards order (palette, image): http://pic.armedcats.net/b/bl/blue/2013/05/15/paletteimage.png

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the fact you're using a GIF palette file instead of a PNG like I am makes the difference. Either way, thanks! (fine to keep the image up, it's public off my blog)